# Vue: select input placeholder option disappears when I add v-model

Tags: html, css, vue.js, drop-down-menu

```
<select
         class="cursoruser-pointer p-2 w-full rounded-full ">
    <option class="rounded-full "
            disabled selected value="">Language to learn</option>
    <option class="rounded-full">German</option>
    <option>Spanish</option>
    <option>English</option>
</select>
```

Shows

[image]

However if I add `v-model = "selectedLanguage"`:

```
<select v-model = "selectedLanguage"
         class="cursoruser-pointer p-2 w-full rounded-full ">
    <option class="rounded-full "
            disabled selected value="">Language to learn</option>
    <option class="rounded-full">German</option>
    <option>Spanish</option>
    <option>English</option>
</select>
```

it stops showing the placeholder:

[image]

```
<script>
    ...

    export default {
        ...
        data: () => ({
                selectedLanguage: 'Language to Learn',
        }),
...
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial `selectedLanguage` value should be `""` (empty string), since you specified the value of "`Language to learn`" option to be empty string (`value=""`). In addition to that, `selected` is not needed anymore since you are already using `v-model`

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-dawn-nu4m8?file=/src/App.vue